# toByteData method (dart:ui.Image) is extremely slow in Dart & Flutter on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to convert a `dart:ui.Image` object to its bytes. So, I used the `toByteData`  method for that. But the method is prolonged, it takes about 15 seconds for a 2 MB image file on an iOS device.

```dart
final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
```

Here is another person who faces the same problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/114788

The bug is actually fixed but hasn't merged into the production yet: https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/34568

I wonder if there is any workaround fix to solve this until the real fix gets merged into the production? Or any alternative way to convert an Image object to its bytes?

Note: The `Image` I am writing about is the `dart:ui.Image`. But not the widget one, or the one in the [Image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image).

Comment: any solution. this png files are too slow in general in the recent updates